# Aspx page to download any type of file from a specific directory on web server

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, iis

I had a quick requirement from my client that he want to store some files in a Folder in web server (we have a temp folder which has rights to allow Everybody).

He want to place the file in that directly and give the link e.g. http://www.abcd.com/temp/somefile.rdl to his customer to directly download the file.

Is there any readymade aspx page available so that I can just use that page set path of folder and it should work this way.

If not can I quickly create it using only aspx page.

I almost did it with the following code in aspx

```
<%
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + Server.MapPath("~/TempReport/"+Request.QueryString["file"]) + "\"");
Response.ContentType = "Application/cab";
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/TempReport/"+Request.QueryString["file"]));
Response.End();
%>
```

The only problem is that I can only download cab type of file due to following line:

```
Response.ContentType = "Application/cab";
```

I want any kind of file to be downloaded.

Comment: Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1910343/30594

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this post for answer, to get MIME type which should be set for your content Type

[Using .NET, how can you find the mime type of a file based on the file signature not the extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510/using-net-how-can-you-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-based-on-the-file-signature)

Or you can just put, which should work fine for downloading binary file.
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

```
        Page.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
        Page.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=""" & strFilename & """")
        Page.Response.OutputStream.Write(objAttachment.Data, 0, objAttachment.Data.Length)
```

Comment: can I download any type of file using binary write?

Comment: Yes you can download any file type, check the edit for code sample