# Get extension from Content-Type

Tags: c#, content-type, file-extension

This is a very straight forward question.

I have a `Content-Type` stored in the form of a string.

Ideally I'd like to infer an extension from that `Content-Type` without having to have a giant nasty switch case.

Is there a built in construct to achieve this?

Btw, I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910097/content-type-by-extension) but that goes the opposite direction from extension to content-type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Get file extension by content type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087808/c-sharp-get-file-extension-by-content-type)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want a `Dictionary`.  This will allow you to look up an extension for a given content type:

```
Dictionary<string, string> extensionLookup = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"ContentType1", ".ext1"},
    {"ContentType2", ".ext2"},
};
```

You can populate the dictionary based on a database table, a file, etc. rather than hard coding the values.

Once you have the `Dictionary` it's as simple as:

```
string extension = extensionLookup[someContentType];
```

Comment: This assumes I know all the possible extensions ahead of time though. And as you know that is almost impossible, right?

Comment: @MikeFielden It makes no such assumption:  `"You can populate the dictionary based on a database table, a file, etc. rather than hard coding the values."`  You'll need to get the mappings from *somewhere*, but you can get those mappings at runtime and add them to the dictionary without knowing what they are at compile time.

Comment: No, I understand what youre saying I was just hoping there was something like Apache's Tika :) for IIS

Comment: The reverse is possible in .NET 4.5, by calling System.Web.MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(string fileName).  I wish there was a way to get the proper file extention for a given content type from IIS as well.

Answer (score 1):

In the registry of my W10 box there is an extensive list mapping content-type to `.extn`:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type]
```

You might like to explore the [HtmlAgilityPack OSS project](https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack) which has source file `HtmlWeb.cs` containing the following methods:

```
public static string GetContentTypeForExtension(string extension, string def)
public static string GetExtensionForContentType(string contentType, string def)
```

There is also [commented-out] Dictionary and population code:

```
//private static Dictionary<string, string> _mimeTypes;
//        _mimeTypes = new Dictionary<string, string>();
//        _mimeTypes.Add(".3dm", "x-world/x-3dmf");
//        _mimeTypes.Add(".3dmf", "x-world/x-3dmf");
//    ...
//        _mimeTypes.Add(".zoo", "application/octet-stream");
//        _mimeTypes.Add(".zsh", "text/x-script.zsh");
```

So you may brew your own (maybe just the common ones that YOUR app needs) for efficiency.

FYI the authoritative list of content-type values and usage is here:
**[www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml)**

Comment: Not sure why was this downvoted, this answer helped me a lot. Upvoting