# C# Get file extension by content type

Tags: c#, content-type

How can I get file extension by content type ?

Example I know that file is "text/css" so extension will be ".css".

```
private static string GetExtension(string contentType)
{
    string ext = ".";

    { DETERMINATION CODE IN HERE }

    return ext;
}
```

Comment: Write and populate `Dicionary` of know types?

Comment: What's with all the down-voting?

Comment: I think the down-voting is because the poster is asking us to write his code for him rather than posting what was tried and asking specific questions.

Comment: If you don't even know where to begin it's hard to write code that you tried.  This seems like a perfectly legitimate, and specific, question to me.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The "Best" solution that I know of is to query the registry.  You can find example code here.
http://cyotek.com/blog/mime-types-and-file-extensions

```
public static string? Extension(string mimeType)
{
    using var key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"MIME\Database\Content Type\" + mimeType, false);
    var value = key?.GetValue("Extension", null);

    return value?.ToString();
}
```

Also please note that this solution will only be available on Windows only `RegistryKey.OpenSubKey(string, bool)` is only supported on: 'windows'.

Comment: `using Microsoft.Win32;`

Comment: This works if the system you are getting the extension from can open the file. For an xls, you need Excel installed etc

Comment: Hi @mayowa ogundele, What is the alternate solution for getting file extension based on content type if system cannot open the file. We cannot use dictionary as it does not accept duplicate Keys (as content types repeat). Please suggest..Thank You!

Comment: Hi Bhargav, you may want to try MediaTypeMap from Nuget. see link https://github.com/samuelneff/MimeTypeMap#getting-the-extension-to-a-mime-type. Hope it suffices for you

Comment: Won't work for .net core running on different os

Answer (score 65):

### [2019] .NET Core / Standard compatible portable way

While Bradley's answer continues to be perfect on regular old Windows machines running .NET Framework, `Registry` is Windows-specific and **will fail when porting the app to a non-Windows environment**.

Fortunately there is a very small NuGet library that essentially contains a hardcoded map of the official MIME types and corresponding extensions **without any external dependencies** here: https://github.com/samuelneff/MimeTypeMap. It is available on NuGet as [MediaTypeMap](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MediaTypeMap/). After installing the package calling it is as simple as:

```
MimeTypeMap.GetExtension("audio/wav")
```

To put it into your example you can simply:

```
private static string GetExtension(string contentType)
{
    return MimeTypes.MimeTypeMap.GetExtension(contentType);
}
```

Comment: The one line of code is that's  why I love lazy developers!

Comment: Awesome stuff works perfectly since my webapp runs on Azure can't rely on the registry method

Comment: It's true, this project exists. But unfortunately, it is badly maintained. The NuGet package is now over several years outdated and does not match the version of the source code...