# Download any kind of files using WebClient or HttpClient?

Tags: c#, download

I know there are other questions similar to mine. But the problem I face is different.

I want to download any file. It could be an Image, PDF, Video. The thing is I won't be able to know the file that I'm downloading. That means I don't know the file name. So I tried the following:

#1:

```
private Task<string> DownloadFile(Uri fileUri, string locationToStoreTo)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.OpenRead(fileUri);

        var headerContentDisposition = client.ResponseHeaders["content-disposition"];
        var fileName = new ContentDisposition(headerContentDisposition).FileName;
        var generatedName = GeneratePath(locationToStoreTo, fileName);
            
        client.DownloadFile(fileUri, generatedName);

        return Task.FromResult<string>(generatedName);
     }
}
```

#2:

```
private async Task<string> DownloadFile(Uri fileUri, string locationToStoreTo)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    using (var response = await client.GetAsync(fileUri))
    {
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
          
        var fileName = response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;
        var generatedName = GeneratePath(locationToStoreTo, fileName);

        var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

        using (var fileStream = File.Create(generatedName))
        {
            stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
        return generatedName;

    }
}
```

But in both ways ContentDisposition is null. When I try to find out if the file name is being sent from one of the URLs, I can see that Firefox knows the file name of the file that I'm trying to download.

What am I missing? Is there another way that I can do this?

Comment: Use Fiddler, or similar, to study the request headers that Firefox sends, and modify your request headers to match. If your request headers are exactly the same as Firefox is sending, and if Firefox has `Content-Disposition` set in the response, then you will also have it set in the response.

Comment: @RB the OP is asking about the *client* and how to determine the filename of the download response. Which only makes sense if the Uri doesn't already contain the filename

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think he's asking "why does Firefox get told what the filename should be, but my client doesn't". The answer then is "make your client behave like Firefox" (unless I've completely misread the question).

Comment: @RB `DownloadFile` is the equivalent of `Save Page`. The response is saved to a file even if it *doesn't* contain a `Content-Disposition` header. Firefox will fail to save anything as well, if there is no `Content-Disposition` header. Since any browser sends a simple `GET` when clicking a link, I suspect that either the URI is different or that the page is actually a form, resulting in a `POST`

Comment: Do you have an example URL where Firefox succeeds at discovering the filename, but your code doesn't have a "content-disposition" response header for the same url?

Comment: @ash do you get any results at all? `DownloadFile` sends a `GET`, equivalent to clicking on a simple link. Perhaps the web page uses a Form, or JavaScript to send a *different* request?

Comment: @ash using `async` and `Task.FromResult` is pointless. The call will still block while claiming that it won't. You should use `await DownloadFileAsync` and return the generated name.

Comment: @Nathan check this url https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xaf1/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/14238349_1059203807529090_1330260415397825692_n.jpg?oh=ecc92a8f458e0a4fc22a4f4bc2ab31b0&oe=588460B0&__gda__=1480608123_255fcfe03eca9000a964fe5d15a425c9

Comment: @Panagiotis yes I did get a result and I can even save the file if I know the file name, but an error will be raised when I try to access the Content Disposition class.

And Thanks for your advice on async and Task.FromResult I will try to use what you suggested

Comment: Did you already step in with debugger and inspect the available headers for each approach?

Comment: @ash for this example URL, the browser can extract the filename right out of the url by taking the last part before the query string, so 14238349_1059203807529090_1330260415397825692_n.jpg will be the filename. Also the response headers will contain which type of file it is (for this example image/jpeg). Is this the filename firefox uses for this url?

Comment: What URL? Firefox may simply extract the filename from the URL even if the server doesn't send a header. The server doesn't *have* to send the Content-Disposition header. In fact, `Content-Disposition` [isn't even part of the HTTP standard](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6266). It contains extra processing info that the server *may* send to the client

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. @Panagiotis can you check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087808/c-sharp-get-file-extension-by-content-type. Bradley Uffner answer worked. Any suggestion on the answer?