# Adding File Extension Based on ContentType in Filename from .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, backend

I need to save the file with its uploaded file extension. For example, if the file name is **"Test_upload"** I must append the file extension to that name. Therefore, I only have the content type available. Also Below is the Sample code

```
       if (suggestedFileName != null && !System.IO.Path.HasExtension(suggestedFileName))
      {
    // Get the file extension from the ContentType
    string[] contentTypeParts = HttpContext.Request.ContentType.Split('/');
    if (contentTypeParts.Length == 2)
    {
        string fileExtension = contentTypeParts[1];

        // Handle spreadsheets differently
        if (fileExtension == "vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
        {
            // For spreadsheet, use '.xlsx' extension
            suggestedFileName = $"{suggestedFileName}.xlsx";
        }
        else
        {
            // For other file types, append the retrieved extension
            suggestedFileName = $"{suggestedFileName}.{fileExtension}";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Default to '.txt' extension if content type doesn't have two parts
        suggestedFileName = $"{suggestedFileName}.txt";
    }
}
```

How to handle any kind of ContentType Can someone help with this

Comment: Think this answer would be sufficient: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56220004/9096402

Comment: Thank you I need to implement without any additional Nuget package

Comment: IMHO, for security reasons you shouldn't trust the mimetype, the filename, or the extension.  That's all untrusted user-input.  You should be in full control of the name and extension.  Case/switch based on received extension, and explicitly create both the filename and extension.  Default case would be to not write/store the file.

Comment: No nuget packages? What kind of requirement is that?

Comment: If you don't want to use the NuGet package just copy the single-file source. It's open source and available on Github.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this code:

```
{
    {"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "xlsx"},
    {"application/pdf", "pdf"},
    {"image/jpeg", "jpg"},
    {"image/png", "png"},
    {"text/plain", "txt"},
};

if (suggestedFileName != null && !System.IO.Path.HasExtension(suggestedFileName))
{
    string contentType = HttpContext.Request.ContentType;
    string fileExtension = "txt"; 
    if (mimeTypeToExtension.TryGetValue(contentType, out var extension))
    {
        fileExtension = extension;
    }
    else
    {
        string[] contentTypeParts = contentType.Split('/');
        if (contentTypeParts.Length == 2)
        {
            string subtype = contentTypeParts[1];
            fileExtension = subtype;
        }
    }
    suggestedFileName += $".{fileExtension}";
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can parse the byte header to get the extension(using a directory) and then append it with string concatenation.
Research magic numbers for further help!

Comment: Excel like all Office formats is a ZIP package containing XML files. Other file formats work the same way. The only thing the header will tell is you that you have an archive

Comment: https://readxl.tidyverse.org/reference/excel_format.html

Comment: That proves my point - the XLSX header is [the same ZIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)): `PK\x03\x04` or, all in hex, `\x50\x4B\x03\x04`